# I have a box with 200 unique cards. When I draw a card, I remove it from the box. On average, how many cards must I draw to get n particular cards?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have almost no background in statistics, however I am very good at interpreting equations and need to answer this question for a spreadsheet I am working on. If you don't want to answer this problem, any explanation of the concepts needed to understand this problem or just the names of the concepts so I can do further research would be very helpful.

Comment: Try asking an easier question first:  how many cards do you need to draw (on average) in order to draw one specific card?

Comment: This would be helpful as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking:  how many cards must you draw to *be sure* to get $n$ specific cards, then the answer is all $200$, since you may not get all the cards you want until the very last one.

If that is not what you meant, then please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, to clarify I meant on average, say after an infinite amount of trials.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/852829)

Comment: @SahibaArora You are right.  I posted this before the OP edited the question and made it more clear. I'll delete the answer momentarily.